# Insert related object id in one transaction when objects don't have foreign key relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In situation like this (FK between Customer and Order exists) all objects are saved during same transaction:

```
var customer = new Customer(); 
var order = new Order { Customer = customer }; 
context.Orders.Add(order);
context.SaveChanges();
```

What if I have situation like this:

```
public class Log 
{
     public int ObjectId { get; set; }
     public string ObjectType { get; set; }
     public string ActivityDescription { get; set;}
}
```

Log class can be reused for multiple objects so I can't create appropriate FK.
So, I need to call SaveChanges in order to get customer id:

```
var customer = new Customer(); 
context.SaveChanges();

Log log = new Log() { ObjectId=customer.Id, 
                      ObjectType=customer.GetType().FullName, 
                      ActivityDescription = "customer created" };
context.Logs.Add(order);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Is there a way to insert both customer and log objects inside same transaction like in situations where FK is configured?

Comment: Can you provide different nullable foreign keys in your `Log` entity? Can you create a base class for all the entities which can be used for log entries, so you can use a foreign key on the base class?

Comment: @Progman Not really, there is a lot of classes and they are not really related to each other. If there isn't solution that would mimic FK behaviour using EF config I would go with double SaveChanges call.

Comment: [Using Transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions). Manually call `BeginTransaction()` and `Commit()`